# Reducing the amount of imported libraries in Python

Tags: python, import, minimize

I am using the Button, Entry, Label element, as well as using winfo_screenwidth(), winfo_screenwidth(), and the geometry() function for my main window. On the Entry elements I am only using the get() and delete() functions.

```
from Tkinter import *
def main():
    window = Tk()
    window.title('cool stuff')

    width = 750
    height = 60

    screenw = window.winfo_screenwidth()
    screenh = window.winfo_screenheight()

    posx = (screenw/2) - (width/2)
    posy = (screenh/2) - (height/2)

    window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, posx, posy))

    Label(window, text='enter text: ').pack(side=LEFT)
    textEntry = Entry(window)
    textEntry.config(width=16)
    textEntry.pack(side=LEFT)

    submitButton = Button(window, text='Submit', width=12, command=lambda: buttonCallback(textEntry))
    submitButton.pack()
    window.mainloop()

# in buttonCallback Entry.get() and Entry.delete() functions are used...
```

Is there a way to make my imports weigh less in this scenario? I am trying to compile the python file to .exe, but it requires a lot of files by its side to function. It would also make sense to shrink down imports in a lot of other cases, because I guess you'd want less overhead for your python files to run faster.

Comment: you could try `from Tkinter import what_you_need`?

Comment: Closely related question though not an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877218/python-imports

Comment: FWIW, doing `from Tkinter import *` clutters your namespace with 175 names.

Comment: if you want small .exe, python is probably not a great choice ... I have yet to have less than a 10 MB exe from python programs ... (maybe a slight exaggeration) ... to be fair GUI's take a lot of resources, and im not sure it would be alot smaller in any other language. ..

Comment: ... you are only importing `Tkinter`... it is only one file... do you mean you want to package your python app without including the tk resources?

Comment: At the end of the day, the .exe will need to contain a Python installation and then the GUI library will probably double the size. From my experience, both are about 6 MB, which isn't unreasonable. I don't think specific imports will reduce the file size since the entire script will need to be packaged (you have no way to know there isn't a module-scoped variable that needs to be initialized). IMO, it's probably not worth it to look into this too much.

Comment: the problem is, I am not sure what_I_need, for example:
I can not seem to find a way to use Tk() without importing the whole library, and I can not find a way to import functions like winfo_screenwidth().
Writing
`from Tkinter import Tk` won't work,
`from Tkinter import geometry` won't work,
`from Tkinter import Button, Label, Entry` works though

However, if I need to use Tk() I can not find a way to do so without importing the whole Tkinter library :/

Comment: Sorry if my earlier comment was misleading. It was **only** an incidental remark to mention the clutter that star imports create, and the potential for name clashes. When you do _any_ import the whole module _has_ to be loaded. Eg, if you do `from Tkinter import Button` the whole Tkinter module is loaded, but only the `Button` name appears in the current namespace. If the whole module wasn't loaded then `Button` wouldn't have access to the Tkinter stuff it needs to do its job. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/187471

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I didn't know it worked that way :P

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: tkinter is much more than a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing you can do to make the tkinter imports 'weigh less", if by that you mean a smaller memory footprint.

You must import all of Tkinter in order for it to be usable; you can't pick and choose a subset of widgets from Tkinter. The bulk of the tkinter code isn't even python; tkinter is a thin wrapper around a complete tcl interpreter and tk GUI library, which must be imported as an atomic unit.